# When analyzing the time series data every half hour, is there a method to quickly calculate the daily average of the data of each column

Tags: r, dplyr

```
Daily_mean<-Half_hourly%>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byzre.png)

Is there a good way to average each column in terms of the day step size？

Comment: You were almost there, you just need to group by the final unit you want. eg 
`Half_hourly %>% mutate(Day = round.POSIXt(Date, "day")) %>% group_by(Day)` ... in general in the future provide data as a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) instead of as a screenshot if you want people to actually be able to use your data to help

Comment: Please share a reproducible dataset using the `dput` function. Here is how: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg